# How to find where is the error value in the Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

```
C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3 2'
```

How can I find where in my dataset this error '3 2' value is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use equality comparison

`df.isin(["3 2"]).any()`

If you need the co-ordinates then

`df[df.isin(["3 2"])].stack()`